# Combining two variables, missing in one and non-missing in another

Tags: stata

I have two columns in my dataframe. One includes vaccination rates for the flu from 2000 to 2004 and the other contains vaccination rates for the flu from 2005 to 2006. I am trying to merge them into a single column to perform a t-test. So far, I tried

```
gen amin_vaccination = amin_number + number_amin
```

which yielded a blank column. Any recommendations on how I can do this? For reference, the dataframe essentially looks like this:

```
Year   flu_vaccine   flu_vaccination_rate
2001   .12
2002   .14
2003   .15 
2004   .13
2005                 .145
2006                 .125
```

I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
Year  vaccination_rate
2001   .12
2002   .14
2003   .15 
2004   .13
2005   .145
2006   .125
```

Answer (score 1):

The missing values in the columns are treated as "undefined" and you can't do math on undefined values, so the result in `gen amin_vaccination = amin_number + number_amin` is also undefined as at least one of the values for each observation is undefined.

Instead do:

`egen amin_vaccination = rowtotal(amin_number  number_amin)`

See `help egen` for many more functions other than `rowtotal()` that will help you avoid this in the future.

Note: Since you seem to come from R or Python, what is called column in those languages are called a variable in Stata. I do not want to come across as picky with terminology but that will help you read Stata help files

Comment: `egen` will work fine, but a glance at the code with `viewsource egen.ado` shows quite an overhead in interpreted code.

Comment: In a strong sense you can do math(ematics) with numeric missings, but the answer is numeric missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
gen wanted = min(flu_vaccine, flu_vaccination_rate) 

gen wanted = max(flu_vaccine, flu_vaccination_rate)

replace flu_vaccine = flu_vaccination_rate if missing(flu_vaccine)
```

are some other solutions. It may seem puzzling or even paradoxical that `min()` and `max()` are both solutions, but what does the work in either case is that missing values are ignored to the extent possible, so whenever one argument is not missing and the other is missing, the non-missing value is always returned as result.